# Argument list when calling a function

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I'm using the Mac OS X version of Sublime Text 2. The autocomplete of a function is pretty nice - but I'm wondering if it's possible to have an argument list when you are calling a function to remind yourself how many and what arguments need to be passed? My function is defined as:

```
import math

def area_polygon(n, s):
  return (0.25 * n * s ** 2) / math.tan(math.pi / n)
```

It would be useful if I get an argument list after I type area_polygon() within the brackets (or as a dropdown) so I know what to pass in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a source code analysis plugin; there are several to choose from, offering different levels of integration and auto-completion, and support for Sublime Text 2 and / or 3.

- [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel) - *Full-featured code intelligence and smart autocomplete engine*
- [SublimePythonIDE](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimePythonIDE) - *ST3 only: A rewrite of SublimeRope for ST3, uses the Rope library to add python completions and refactoring to ST3*
- [Python-Auto-Complete](https://github.com/eliquious/Python-Auto-Complete) - *A Sublime Text 2 plugin which adds additional auto-completion capability to Python scripts*
- [SublimeRope](https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimeRope) - *ST2 only, use SublimePythonIDE with ST3: Adds Python completions and some IDE-like functions to Sublime Text 2, through the use of the Rope library*

All packages are available through [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).